# not able to set bind-address=[ip of my server] in mysql

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

I want to create a master-slave replication on ubuntu servers.
both(master and slave) on different servers.
i made my.cnf(without coments) file on master as:

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
[mysqld]
bind-address=my_server_ip
server-id=1
log_bin=/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog_do_db=indicators
```

then i restart using sudo service mysql restart and get the following error:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details
```

but when i set bind-address=127.0.0.1 it works fine.

below is the reference is used which says bind-address should be the address of master server

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql

but it contadicts with below link which says(under comments section) bind-address is the ip of slave

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-howto-masterbaseconfig.html

**systemctl status mysql.service** as in above error code

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: 
enabled)
Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2017-11-04 
07:12:12 UTC; 11s ago
Process: 25213 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 25205 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre 
(code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 25213 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE);         : 25214 (mysql-
systemd-s)
   Tasks: 2
   Memory: 400.0K
   CPU: 250ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
       └─control
         ├─25214 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
         └─25267 sleep 1

Nov 04 07:12:12 fundexpert-test-r systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-
off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 04 07:12:12 fundexpert-test-r systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community 
Server.
Nov 04 07:12:12 fundexpert-test-r systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community 
Server...
Nov 04 07:12:14 fundexpert-test-r systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process 
exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

**journalctl -xe** says:

```
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Nov 04 07:12:42 fundexpert-test-r systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered 
failed state.
Nov 04 07:12:42 fundexpert-test-r systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with 
result 'exit-code'.
Nov 04 07:12:43 fundexpert-test-r systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-
off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 04 07:12:43 fundexpert-test-r systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community 
Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
Nov 04 07:12:43 fundexpert-test-r systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community 
Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
```

Answer (score 0):

> below is the reference is used which says bind-address should be the address of master server

No it doesn't. It says 'replace the standard IP address with the IP address of server'. The word 'master' does not appear.

> but it contadicts with below link which says(under comments section) bind-address is the ip of slave

No it doesn't. It says 'you will have to make sure that the *slave's* address or hostname is matched by the bind-address setting'.

You cannot bind to a non-local IP address.

Comment: they used following ip's:12.34.56.789- Master Database

12.23.34.456- Slave Database and it used bind-address=12.34.56.789, so it meant they used masters database ip.

Comment: You need to read more carefully. That is in a section entitled 'Step One—Configure the Master Database' and beginning with 'open up the mysql configuration file on the master server.' The other sections is about configuring the slave. A section about configuring the master cannot contract a section about configuring the slave.